# UICollectionViewCell not detecting touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I've tried adding a UIButton to the cell's contentView, which wasn't getting called. Then I tried adding a touchesBegan method to the cell. It's not being called. The cell has it's background color being set, and I can see in the extrapolated view that XCode now provides that it's the topmost view.

Any thoughts as to why interaction might not be working?

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 0):

I think answer lies into UICollectionView delegate methods and datasource, you don't need touchedBegun etc, 
I guess you want to know which cell has been tapped. More codes will definitely helps. 
In storyboard do this,
A viewController with UICollectionViewCell inside it.
Add UIViewController subclass in your project and make your storyboards viewController as its subclass. 
Add UICollectionView subclass and make your UICollectionViewCell its subclass.

read upon this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12